# Matlab code for iterated function system

Tags: matlab, iterated-function-system

$f_1(x)=1.2x(1-x), f_2(x)=2.8x(1-x)$  on  $\mathbb R$, Now from a starting point $x_0=0.25$,an the iterated function system $x_{n+1}=f_{\omega_n}(x_n), n=0,1,2,\dots$
 where $\omega_n$ are i.i.d discrete random variable taking values in $\{1,2\}$. Could anyone help me to create a Matlab code for this system to generate the random points $x_n$?

I was trying this assuming probability of appearing the first function is $0.65$ and for the second function is $0.35$.

```
x0=0.25;
r_weights= [0.65; 1];
f1=@(x) 1.2* x*(1-x);
f2=@(x) 2.8*x*(1-x);
x = zeros(n,1);
y = zeros(n,1);

    n=500000;
for i=1:n-1
    r = rand;
    choice = find(cumweight >r, 1 );
    switch (choice)
        case 1
            f1(i+1)=f1(x0);
        case 2 
            f2(i+1)=f2(x0);

    end
end
```

Comment: Relevant [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30315) on coding problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try running your code or the corrections I'm proposing below, but the main points are:

1- You have defined function handles, but I would suggest defining functions separately for readability and modularity.

2- Use `xn` (or similar) instead of `x0` for your looping variable.

```
xn = 0.25; 
r_weights = [0.65; 1]; 
n=500000;    
x = zeros(n,1); 
y = zeros(n,1);

for i=1:n-1
    r = rand;
    choice = find(r_weights >r, 1 );
    switch (choice)
        case 1
            x(i+1)=f1(xn);
        case 2 
            x(i+1)=f2(xn);

    end
 xn = x(i+1)
 end


function [y] = f1(x)
y= 1.2* x*(1-x); 
end

function [y] = f2(x)
y= 2.8*x*(1-x);
end
```

Comment: Also, don't we need to define the functions before the for loop?

Comment: This is Matlab and not C. Functions are searched in Matlab's path (i.e. a list of directories, that includes those in `matlabroot` and the current folder plus addedpaths). If, however, defining functions at the end of a script does not work for you, it means you are using a not-so-old version of Matlab, in which case I'd suggest you define each function on a separate file.

Comment: Note that if you try to define a function at the beginning of the file, Matlab will assume the whole file is one function plus its subfunctions, hence you won't be allowed to place commands outside the functions.

Comment: One more question: Is the randomness I have defined in the theory part, followed in the coding part? I mean the way $\omega_n$ are defined is our r_weights same?